# ¿Qué método podría usar para mostrar la duración total de una lista de reproducción?

Tags: java-8

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
public Duration getDuracion() {

    return canciones.stream().mapToLong(c-> c.getDuracion());

}
```

Este proyecto es el de spotify con java 8, lo que quiero es por medio de un stream obtener la duración total de esa lista de reproducción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás devolviendo es un stream con todas las duraciones de las canciones. Como lo que quieres es un único valor, necesitas usar una [reducción](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction).

Puedes usar la operación terminal [`LongStream#sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#sum--) que es un caso especial de reducción, y te devolverá la suma de las duraciones, o `0` si el stream está vacío:

```
long segundos = canciones.stream().mapToLong(c -> c.getDuracion()).sum();
```

Luego, para pasarlo a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), puedes usar el método factoría [`Duration#ofSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofSeconds-long-):

```
return Duration.ofSeconds(segundos);
```